# How to iterate ListView and get item using MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

After the getting the data from backend using webservice, how to iterate the ListView and get the item one by one from it After user has changed or edit the Editext.

```
<LinearLayout>
   <MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/ls_contact"
        android:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/Item_Contact_List"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource PPL" />

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/> 
</LinearLayout>



Item_Contact_List.axml:


<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        local:MvxBind="Text Name" />
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/tv_contactno"
       local:MvxBind="Text ContactNo" />
</LinearLayou



----------- In ViewModel


1. Use the webservice to get the data from BackEnd 

in ViewModel :

 OnCreate()
 { 
   _ppl = WebSvc.getContact() //-- this is webservice

 }


 private People _ppl = new People();


 public People PPL
 {
     get { return this._ppl; }
     set { 
           this._ppl = value; 

          this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PPL); 
        }
 }



2. When user click the Submit button 

Question :

How to iterate the ListView and to get the tv_name and tv_contactno
```

Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What does this have to do with MvvmCross?

Comment: User allow to edit the number and click submit button. Not sure how to do it in MvvmCross for iterating the ListView and get the items.value  and send back to backend. would appreciate if you can show me an example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the list `PPL` will have the changed items... The bind is made directly to the binded list. You should see this if you iterate throw your `PPL` property when the submit

Comment: will check it out. Saw some android example that use diff method and Thought it will be different in MvvmCross.